# Sum of the squares of numbers

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

[image]

Let $x$ and $y$ be the two numbers so that:

$$x^2 + y^2 = A^2$$

$$xy = A^2 + 2A + 2$$

$$xy - x^2 - y^2 = 2A + 2$$

$$\frac{xy - x^2 - y^2}{2} -1 = A$$

So what can I do?

Comment: Substitute 4 into everything else if you want to take the "easiest" way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have:

$$x^2+y^2=A^2$$

$$2xy=2A^2+4A+4$$

So:

$$x^2-2xy+y^2=-A^2-4A-4$$

$$(x-y)^2=-(A+2)^2$$

We know that $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$ and $-(A+2)^2 \leq 0$, so there is one possible value of $A$, it's $A=-2$.

Substitute A = -2 back into the both equations to get $$x^2+y^2=4$$ $$2xy = 4$$
Subtract the two equations to get $(x-y)^2=0$ => $x=y$.

Put this back in the first equation to get $x = y = \pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: But $A=0$ is also possible (though this doesn't change the solutions for $(x,y)$ ).

Comment: No, it's not pościele - first edition is different.

Comment: right! forgot they're squared.